# Moving Grid layout within React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid, material-design

Hello i need to move my grids to display the following layout

[image]

However right now my layout looks like this 
    [image]

I am still trying to understand how grid work, below is my attempt at formatting the grid, however it doesn't want to align itself in the manor of which i wish

```
    <Grid item xs={8}>
            <Grid className = {classes.root} container direction ="column"
                alignItems="flex-start">
                {/* <Typography variant="title" style={{ }}>example</Typography> */}
                <Paper className = {classes.mainDetailsPaper}>
                    <Typography variant="title">Main Details</Typography><Divider />
                    <Typography variant="subheading">Organisation: </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="subheading">Category: </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="subheading">Sub Category: </Typography>
                </Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid className = {classes.root} container direction ="row"
            alignItems="flex-end">
                <Paper className = {classes.subDetailsPaper}>
                    <Typography variant="title">Contract Dates</Typography><Divider />
                    <Typography variant="subheading">Start Date: </Typography>
                </Paper>
                <Paper className = {classes.subDetailsPaper}>
                    <Typography variant="title">Valuation</Typography><Divider />
                    <Typography variant="subheading">Estimated Contract Value: </Typography>
                </Paper>
                <Paper className = {classes.subDetailsPaper}>
                    <Typography variant="title">Supplier Info</Typography><Divider />
                </Paper>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```